# Calculating effective shop inventories from CSV files

Tags: c++, c++11, csv, hash-map, makefile

### Program purpose

The purpose for the program is to create a file containing the effective inventory for each stocked item stored in a collection of shops.

### Input and algorithm details

For clarity, in the descriptions below, variables in the C++ program use this style: `nShopID`, while fields in CSV files are shown like this: *shop_id*.

#### Shops and groups

The problem domain is a collection of **shops** (identified by an `int` shop ID number)  each of which is assigned to a **group** (also identified by an `int`).  The association between `nShopID` and `nGroupID` is contained in a text file `shopgroups.csv`, which is a tab-delimited file with a header with two fields: *shop_id* and *shopgroup_id*.

#### Simple inventory

The **simple inventory** is in a file named `shopstock_all.csv`.  That file is also a tab-delimited file with header containing three fields: *item_idx*, *shop_id*, and *amount*.  The *item_idx* field is a string containing the item identifier, and the *shop_id* represents the shop that has the item and *amount* is an integer representing the quantity of the item at that shop.

#### Effective inventory

The *simple inventory* is simply the number of items at each shop, as described above, but the desired **effective inventory** takes into account the fact that the inventory of nearby shops could, if needed, be quickly moved to one particular shop.  Thus, the *effective inventory* of a particular shop represents the *simple inventory* of that shop plus that of nearby stores.  Nearby stores and the direction of possible movement of inventory is represented in a third tab-delimited file called `sgm.csv` which contains a header and two fields:  *shop_group_from* and *shop_group_to*.  For example, a line in the file might say `8   15` which means that any inventory in group 8 can be counted in the effective inventory of all shops in group 15.  These associations are many-to-many (that is group 8 might feed multiple groups and group 15 might be fed from multiple other groups) and not necessarily reciprocal.  That is, group 8 inventory may be moved to group 15 shops but not necessarily the other direction unless explicitly stated in the file.

Additionally, all shops within the same group also share their effective inventory without needing a special line in the `sgm.csv` file.

Finally, some warehouse shops (those with `nShopID > 10000`) have extra storage available and goods are only transferred *from* and never *to* such shops.  To differentiate, the program actually calculates two effective inventory quantities for each store; `nTotalAmount` which is the effective inventory from all stores including these warehouse shops and `nTotalAmount10k` which is the effective inventory excluding these warehouse shops.

### Output file

The output file is a tab-delimited file with no header with each record (line) containing four  fields: *itemID*, *shopID*, *totalAmount*, *totalAmount10k* each of which has been described above.  The order of the records within the file does not matter.

### The code

The code and sample files are all on [on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/pk72/shop-stock-total)

### Questions

Since I rarely write C++ code, I've got a mix of C++ and C code. Could it be fixed without hurting performance?

What should be fixed to improve readability, naming of variables and code styling?

Could makefile be less "bloated"? (This is the 2nd one I've ever written.)

P.S. I'm using vim, so there are

```
// {{{ manual-style folding comments
// ...
// }}}
```

and I would prefer to leave those as is.

### shop_stock_total.h

```
// {{{ Structures and typedefs
// {{{ ShopGroupMove
typedef list<int> GroupsFromList;
struct ShopGroupMoveStruct {
    int nGroupTo;
    GroupsFromList *lstGroupsFrom;
};
typedef unordered_map<int, struct ShopGroupMoveStruct> ShopGroupMovesMap;
// }}}
// {{{ ShopGroup
typedef list<int> ShopsList;
struct ShopGroupStruct {
    int nGroupID;
    ShopsList *lstShops; // all shops with the same group
};
typedef unordered_map<int, struct ShopGroupStruct> ShopGroupsMap;
// }}}
// {{{ Shop
struct ShopStruct {
    int nShopID;
    int nGroupID;
    ShopsList *lstFromAll;
    ShopsList *lstFrom10k;
};
typedef unordered_map<int, struct ShopStruct> ShopsMap;
// }}}
// {{{ Availability
struct AvailabilityStruct {
    int nShopID;
    int nAmount;
    int nTotalAmount;
    int nTotalAmount10k;
};
typedef unordered_map<int, struct AvailabilityStruct> AvailabilitiesMap;
// }}}
// {{{ ShopStock 
struct ShopStockStruct {
    char *sItemID;
    AvailabilitiesMap *mapAv;
};
typedef unordered_map<std::string, struct ShopStockStruct> ShopStocksMap;
// }}}
// }}}
// {{{ Functions
// {{{ APP specific
void ProcessShopGroupMoves(ShopGroupMovesMap *mapSGM);
void DebugPrintSGM(ShopGroupMovesMap *mapSGM);
void ProcessShopGroups(ShopGroupsMap *mapSG, ShopsMap *mapS);
void DebugPrintSG(ShopGroupsMap *mapSG, ShopsMap *mapS);
void Fill_FromShopAll(ShopGroupMovesMap *mapSGM, ShopGroupsMap *mapSG, ShopsMap *mapS); 
void DebugPrintS(ShopsMap *mapS);
void ProcessShopStocks(ShopStocksMap *mapSS, ShopsMap *mapS, FILE *out);
void PostProcessItem(ShopStockStruct *pstSS, ShopsMap *mapS, FILE *out); 
void DebugPrintSS(ShopStockStruct *pstSS); 
void WriteResult(ShopStockStruct *pstSS, FILE *out);
// }}}
// {{{ generic
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems); 
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim); 
// }}}
// }}}
```

---

### shop_stock_total.cpp

```
// {{{ standard and other includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
// }}}
// {{{ filenames 
const char *SHOP_GROUP_MOVES_FILE = "sgm.csv";
const char *SHOP_GROUPS_FILE = "shopgroups.csv";
const char *SHOP_STOCKS_FILE = "shopstock_all.csv";
const char *SHOP_STOCK_TOTALS_FILE = "shop_stock_total.csv";
// }}}

using namespace std;

#include "shop-stock-total.h"


// {{{ main
int main() {

    // ShopGroupMoves
    ShopGroupMovesMap *mapSGM;
    mapSGM = new ShopGroupMovesMap();
    ProcessShopGroupMoves(mapSGM);
    DebugPrintSGM(mapSGM);


    // ShopGroups and Shops
    ShopGroupsMap *mapSG;
    mapSG = new ShopGroupsMap();
    ShopsMap *mapS;
    mapS = new ShopsMap();
    ProcessShopGroups(mapSG, mapS);
    DebugPrintSG(mapSG, mapS);
    Fill_FromShopAll(mapSGM, mapSG, mapS);
    DebugPrintS(mapS);

    // ShopStock
    ShopStocksMap *mapSS;
    mapSS = new ShopStocksMap();
    FILE* fileSST = fopen (SHOP_STOCK_TOTALS_FILE, "w+");
    ProcessShopStocks(mapSS, mapS, fileSST);
    fclose(fileSST);

    return 0;
}
// }}}
// {{{ ProcessShopGroupMoves
void ProcessShopGroupMoves(ShopGroupMovesMap *mapSGM) {
    std::ifstream file(SHOP_GROUP_MOVES_FILE);
    std::string l;
    ShopGroupMoveStruct *pstSGM;
    int nKey = -1;
    int nSGMs = 0;
    int nGroupFrom;
    int nGroupTo;
    std::vector<std::string> vsItems;
    while (std::getline(file, l)) {
        // skip first line
        if (nKey < 0) {
            nKey = 0;
            continue;
        }
        vsItems = split(l, (char) '\t');
        if (vsItems.size() < 2) 
            continue;

        nGroupFrom = atoi(vsItems[0].c_str());
        nGroupTo = atoi(vsItems[1].c_str());

        auto sgm = mapSGM->find(nGroupTo);
        if (sgm == mapSGM->end()) {
            // not found, so we need to create a new one
            pstSGM = new ShopGroupMoveStruct();
            pstSGM->nGroupTo = nGroupTo;
            pstSGM->lstGroupsFrom = new GroupsFromList();

            // and store it, we'll add from value a bit later
            (* mapSGM)[nGroupTo] = *pstSGM;
        }
        else {
            // found group already, get a pointer to it for adding nGroupFrom
            //   value later
            pstSGM = &(sgm->second);
        }

        // in any case (found or not), we've to add GroupFrom value
        pstSGM->lstGroupsFrom->push_back(nGroupFrom);
        nSGMs++;
    }
    printf("Total %d ShopGroupMoves loaded.\n", nSGMs);
}
// }}}
// {{{ DebugPrintSGM
void DebugPrintSGM(ShopGroupMovesMap *mapSGM) {
    for (auto sgm=mapSGM->begin(); sgm != mapSGM->end(); sgm++) {
        printf("%d:\t", sgm->second.nGroupTo);

        for (auto f=sgm->second.lstGroupsFrom->begin();
                f!=sgm->second.lstGroupsFrom->end(); 
                f++) {
            printf("%d ", *f);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
// }}}
// {{{ ProcessShopGroups
void ProcessShopGroups(ShopGroupsMap *mapSG, ShopsMap *mapS) {
    std::ifstream file(SHOP_GROUPS_FILE);
    std::string l;
    int nSGs = 0;
    int nKey = -1;
    int nShopID;
    int nGroupID;
    ShopStruct *pstShop;
    ShopGroupStruct *pstSG;
    std::vector<std::string> vsItems;
    while (std::getline(file, l)) {
        // skip first line
        if (nKey < 0) {
            nKey = 0;
            continue;
        }
        vsItems = split(l, (char) '\t');
        if (vsItems.size() < 2) 
            continue;

        nShopID = atoi(vsItems[0].c_str());
        nGroupID = atoi(vsItems[1].c_str());

        // skip zero ID shop
        if (nShopID == 0)
            continue;

        // create new Shop and save it
        pstShop = new ShopStruct();
        pstShop->nShopID = nShopID;
        pstShop->nGroupID = nGroupID;
        pstShop->lstFromAll = new ShopsList(); 
        pstShop->lstFrom10k = new ShopsList();

        (* mapS)[nShopID] = *pstShop;

        // do we need to save ShopGroup
        if (nGroupID == 0)
            continue;


        auto sg = mapSG->find(nGroupID);
        if (sg == mapSG->end()) {
            // not found, so we need to create a new one
            pstSG = new ShopGroupStruct();
            pstSG->nGroupID = nGroupID;
            pstSG->lstShops = new ShopsList();

            // and store it, we'll add from value a bit later
            (* mapSG)[nGroupID] = *pstSG;
        }
        else {
            // found group already, get a pointer to it for adding shop 
            //   value later
            pstSG = &(sg->second);
        }

        // in any case (found or not), we've to add GroupFrom value
        pstSG->lstShops->push_back(nShopID);
        nSGs++;


    }
    printf("Total %d ShopGroups loaded.\n", nSGs);

}
// }}}
// {{{ Fill_FromShopAll
void Fill_FromShopAll(ShopGroupMovesMap *mapSGM, ShopGroupsMap *mapSG, ShopsMap *mapS) {
    for (auto s = mapS->begin(); s != mapS->end(); s++) {

        // fill shops from the same group
        auto sg = mapSG->find(s->second.nGroupID);
        if (sg != mapSG->end()) {
            for (auto s_ = sg->second.lstShops->begin();
                    s_ != sg->second.lstShops->end();
                    s_++) {
                s->second.lstFromAll->push_back(*s_);
                        }
        }

        // fill shops from movement groups
        auto sgm = mapSGM->find(s->second.nGroupID);
        if (sgm != mapSGM->end()) {
            for (auto sg = sgm->second.lstGroupsFrom->begin();
                    sg != sgm->second.lstGroupsFrom->end();
                    sg++) {
                auto sg_ = mapSG->find(*sg);
                if (sg_ != mapSG->end()) {
                    for (auto s_ = sg_->second.lstShops->begin();
                            s_ != sg_->second.lstShops->end();
                            s_++) {
                        s->second.lstFromAll->push_back(*s_);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // de duping
        s->second.lstFromAll->sort();
        s->second.lstFromAll->unique();

        // remove shop itself
        s->second.lstFromAll->remove(s->second.nShopID);

        // copy to 10k
        /* auto n = std::copy_if( */
        /*         s->second.lstFromAll->begin(), */
        /*         s->second.lstFromAll->end(), */
        /*         s->second.lstFrom10k->begin(), */
        /*         [](int i){return (i < 10000);}); */
        /* s->second.lstFrom10k->size( */
        /* auto n = std::copy( */
        /*         s->second.lstFromAll->begin(), */
        /*         s->second.lstFromAll->end(), */
        /*         s->second.lstFrom10k->begin() */
        /*         ); */
        /* s->second.lstFrom10k->resize( */
        /*         std::distance(s->second.lstFrom10k->begin(), n)); */
        for (auto s_ = s->second.lstFromAll->begin();
                s_ != s->second.lstFromAll->end();
                s_++) {
            if (*s_ < 10000) {
                s->second.lstFrom10k->push_back(*s_);
            }
        }

    }
}
// }}}
// {{{ DebugPrintS
void DebugPrintS(ShopsMap *mapS) {
    for (auto s = mapS->begin(); s != mapS->end(); s++) {
        printf("%d:\t", s->second.nShopID);
        for (auto s_ = s->second.lstFrom10k->begin(); 
                s_ != s->second.lstFrom10k->end();
                s_++) {
            printf("%d, ", *s_);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
// }}}
// {{{ DebugPrintSG
void DebugPrintSG(ShopGroupsMap *mapSG, ShopsMap *mapS) {
    // print shop groups
    for (auto sg=mapSG->begin(); sg != mapSG->end(); sg++) {
        printf("%d:\t", sg->second.nGroupID);

        for (auto s = sg->second.lstShops->begin();
                s != sg->second.lstShops->end();
                s++) {
            printf("%d ", *s);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // print shops
    for ( auto s = mapS->begin(); s != mapS->end(); s++) {
        printf("%d : %d\n", s->second.nShopID, s->second.nGroupID);
    }
}
// }}}
// {{{ PostProcessItem
void PostProcessItem(ShopStockStruct *pstSS, ShopsMap *mapS, FILE *out) {
    AvailabilityStruct *pstAV;
    for (auto s = mapS->begin();
            s != mapS->end();
            s++) {
        // if shop is not present in current item Availability
        //  add it with 0 amounts, 
        //  coz we could still move goods there from others shops
        auto s_ = pstSS->mapAv->find(s->second.nShopID);
        if (s_ == pstSS->mapAv->end()) {
            pstAV = new AvailabilityStruct();
            pstAV->nShopID = s->second.nShopID;
            pstAV->nAmount = 0;
            pstAV->nTotalAmount = 0;
            pstAV->nTotalAmount10k = 0;

            (*(pstSS->mapAv))[s->second.nShopID] = *pstAV;
        }
    }

    // summing up total availability
    for (auto av = pstSS->mapAv->begin();
            av != pstSS->mapAv->end();
            av++) {

        // add amounts from shop itself 
        av->second.nTotalAmount = av->second.nAmount;
        av->second.nTotalAmount10k = av->second.nAmount;

        // add amount from other shops which could move goods into this one
        auto s_ = mapS->find(av->second.nShopID);
        if (s_ == mapS->end()) continue;
        for (auto s__ = s_->second.lstFromAll->begin();
                s__ != s_->second.lstFromAll->end();
                s__++) {
            auto av_ = pstSS->mapAv->find(*s__);
            if (av_ == pstSS->mapAv->end()) continue;
            av->second.nTotalAmount += av_->second.nAmount;
            if (*s__ < 10000) {
                av->second.nTotalAmount10k += av_->second.nAmount;
            }
        }

    }

    //DebugPrintSS(pstSS);
    WriteResult(pstSS, out);
}
// }}}
// {{{ DebugPrintSS
void DebugPrintSS(ShopStockStruct *pstSS) {
    printf("%s:\t", pstSS->sItemID);
    for (auto av = pstSS->mapAv->begin();
            av != pstSS->mapAv->end();
            av++) {
        printf("%d - %d - %d;", av->second.nShopID, av->second.nTotalAmount,
                av->second.nTotalAmount10k);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
// }}}
// {{{ WriteResult
void WriteResult(ShopStockStruct *pstSS, FILE *out) {
    for (auto av = pstSS->mapAv->begin();
            av != pstSS->mapAv->end();
            av++) {
        if (av->second.nTotalAmount + av->second.nTotalAmount10k == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        fprintf(out, "%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",
                pstSS->sItemID,
                av->second.nShopID,
                av->second.nTotalAmount,
                av->second.nTotalAmount10k
                );
    }
}
// }}}
// {{{ ProcessShopStocks
void ProcessShopStocks(ShopStocksMap *mapSS, ShopsMap *mapS, FILE *out) {
    std::ifstream file(SHOP_STOCKS_FILE);
    std::string l;
    ShopStockStruct *pstSS = NULL;
    AvailabilityStruct *pstAV;
    int nKey = -1;
    int nSSs = 0;
    char *sItemID;
    char *sItemIDprev = (char *)"";
    int nShopID;
    int nAmount;
    std::vector<std::string> vsItems;
    while (std::getline(file, l)) {
        // skip first line
        if (nKey < 0) {
            nKey = 0;
            continue;
        }
        vsItems = split(l, (char) '\t');
        if (vsItems.size() < 3) 
            continue;

        sItemID = strdup(vsItems[0].c_str());
        if (strcmp(sItemIDprev, sItemID) != 0) {
            // item changed - post process previous item
            if (pstSS != NULL)
                PostProcessItem(pstSS, mapS, out);
        }
        nShopID = atoi(vsItems[1].c_str());
        nAmount = atoi(vsItems[2].c_str());

        auto ss = mapSS->find(sItemID);
        if (ss == mapSS->end()) {
            // not found, so we need to create a new one
            pstSS = new ShopStockStruct();
            pstSS->sItemID = sItemID;
            pstSS->mapAv = new AvailabilitiesMap();

            // and store it, we'll add from value a bit later
            (* mapSS)[sItemID] = *pstSS;
        }
        else {
            // found group already, get a pointer to it for adding nGroupFrom
            //   value later
            pstSS = &(ss->second);
        }

        // in any case (found or not), we've to add GroupFrom value
        // to do: create struct, and store it in map
        pstAV = new AvailabilityStruct();
        pstAV->nShopID = nShopID;
        pstAV->nAmount = nAmount;
        pstAV->nTotalAmount = 0;
        pstAV->nTotalAmount10k = 0;

        (*(pstSS->mapAv))[nShopID] = *pstAV;

        nSSs++;
    }
    // process the last item if exists 
    if (pstSS != NULL)
        PostProcessItem(pstSS, mapS, out);

    printf("Total %d ShopStocks loaded.\n", nSSs);
}
// }}}
// {{{ Generic split to vector function 
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim, std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        elems.push_back(item);
//      printf("\t%s\n", item.c_str());
    }
    return elems;
}
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
// }}}
```

---

### Makefile:

```
PROGRAM = shop-stock-total
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS := -g -std=c++11 -Wall -O3 -march=native -mtune=native
LDFLAGS := -g -L /usr/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

all: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): $(PROGRAM).gcda $(PROGRAM).o 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -fprofile-use -o $@ $(PROGRAM).o $(LDFLAGS) 

$(PROGRAM).gcda: profile/$(PROGRAM)
    ./profile/$(PROGRAM) >/dev/null
    cp profile/$(PROGRAM).gcda ./

profile/$(PROGRAM): $(PROGRAM).cpp $(PROGRAM).h
    [[ -d profile ]] || mkdir profile
    cp $(PROGRAM).cpp profile/
    cp $(PROGRAM).h profile/
    cd profile && $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -fprofile-generate $(PROGRAM).cpp
    cd profile && $(CXX) $(CXXFLAFS) -fprofile-generate -o $(PROGRAM) $(PROGRAM).o $(LDFLAGS)

shop-stock-total.o: $(PROGRAM).cpp $(PROGRAM).h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -fprofile-use $(PROGRAM).cpp

clean:
    @rm -rf *.o $(PROGRAM) ./profile *.gcda
```

---

Comment: For better performance, try to 1) replace all uses of `std::list` with `std::vector` 2) reduce pointer usage the items pointed to can often be stored by value instead.

Comment: Make better meassuments. How much of those 19s are from reading the file? how much from writing to file?

Comment: juvian, without writing result file cpp version runs 14.3-14.5 seconds.

Comment: I count 18 uses of `new`, but 0 uses of `delete`. I don't think this code is working correctly. Not only that, AFAICT all of those uses of `new` aren't necessary if one were to make minor modifications to the datastructures used.

Comment: The header misses `#include`s. Please go over your code again and make sure it actually works!

Comment: hoffmale, I've replaced one std::list with std::vector, no changes in time running. For the shops list, it uses sort() and unique() to avoid possible duplicates and better printing (sorted). Deletes are missing for sure. However, I didn't get your idea. How could I use pointer to structure without new?  BTW, the data files are available on GitLab and Makefile too. :)

Comment: `ShopList *lstShops;` declares a pointer to a `ShopList`. The `ShopList` object being pointed to is somewhere else in memory (and needs to be constructed somehow, e.g. via `new`). `ShopList lstShops;` declares and default-constructs a `ShopList` object in that place. That's the difference I speak of.

Comment: And pointer dereferences are SLOOOOOW! Every time you see a `*something` or a `something->something_else`, that's very likely a CPU cache miss. `something` or `something.something_else` very likely isn't (unless references get involved). For comparison: A cache miss = 100-1000 CPU cycles worth of computation.

Comment: @pk72 still missing the reading time

Comment: jovian, without further processing - just reading those files even on slow machine takes almost no time: real 0m0.164s
user 0m0.149s
sys 0m0.015s  Thus, all the processing time is hidden somewhere in ProcessShopStocks which calls PostProcessItem

Comment: hoffmale, I've got your idea about pointers and possible cache misses. Will try to rewrite the code to use little to no pointers. Thanks. Anything, else?

Comment: @pk72 have you confirmed that most of the time is from ProcessShopStocks? Its much better to do a lot of profiling and optimizing only the part that is taking most of the processing time than trying to optimize all until the time goes down

Comment: hoffmale, I've removed pointer from ShopStock to mapAv, tested on old PC: before: // real 0m25.495s, after: // real 0m25.296s
struct ShopStockStruct {
    char *sItemID;
    AvailabilitiesMap mapAv;
};
A little bit better, yes. But not that much. More ideas?

Comment: This needs so much work to be good C++. At the moment this C with classes. Its not using automatic variables enough (using too many new), It leaks (not using enough delete), its exception unsafe (not using RIAA), its fragile to change (due to printf), its not move friendly (thus possibly inefficient no move semantics).

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Vogel612, I didn't changed the code from the original question. Just added 1 function to the end. Because the code does not fit into comment section. I'll remove it later from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your program.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Use consistent formatting

The code as posted has inconsistent indentation which makes it hard to read and understand. Pick a style and apply it consistently.

### Don't use Hungarian notation

Prefixing every variable with an abbreviation of its type is usually called "Hungarian notation" and it was once popular.  Even then it was a bad idea.  Don't clutter up your source code with that; instead, concentrate on defining meaningful names for each variable and choose types appropriately.

### Use better naming

The name `mapSGM` is not terrible, because once we figure out that `SGM` stands for "Shop Group Moves" we have, at least, some idea as to what it means.  However many of the names are very poor.  For instance within `PostProcessItem()`, we have `s`, `s_`, `s__`, `av` and `av_`.  In addition to those being very short cryptic names, having deceptively similar names all in the same function is diabolically confusing.

### Understand `new` and `delete`

When you declare a variable such as `std::string item;` it is called an `automatic` variable and needs neither `new` nor `delete`.  It comes into existence and is destroyed as needed and is used rationally within `split()`.  However, many places the code looks more like this:

```
ShopGroupMovesMap *mapSGM;
mapSGM = new ShopGroupMovesMap();
ProcessShopGroupMoves(mapSGM);
```

This is really not a good way to go about things because what `ProcessShopGroupMoves` actually does is to populate an empty container that it's handed.  Better would be to have it return such a structure instead as:

```
auto mapSGM{ProcessShopGroupMoves()};
```

Note that I am using `auto` here and the [uniform initialization syntax](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax) of C++11.

### Don't leak memory

The memory that's allocated via `new` should be freed via `delete` but no such deletions occur within this program.  That's the recipe for a memory leak and really should be addressed.  The best way with modern C++ is to simply avoid explicitly calling `new`, and I'll demonstrate below.

### Consider using range-for syntax

The code for `DebugPrintSGM` currently contains this code in the inner loop:

```
for (auto f=sgm->second.lstGroupsFrom->begin();
    f!=sgm->second.lstGroupsFrom->end(); 
    f++) {
    printf("%d ", *f);
}
```

In addition to being really hard to read and using the antique `printf` (more on that in a moment), it uses iterators when it could be greatly simplified using `range-for` syntax:

```
for (const auto &fromStore : sgm->second.lstGroupsFrom) {
    std::cout << fromStore << ' ';
}
```

Much neater, cleaner and easier to read, understand and maintain.  Using similar syntax for the outer loop will also clean up the syntax for this loop.

### Allow the user to specify input and output files

The file names are currently hardcoded which certainly greatly restricts the usefulness of the program.  Consider using `argc` and `argv` to allow the user to specify file names on the command line.

### Use objects better

The code uses unaugmented data structures such as `std::list`, but uses `typedef` and forgoes adding application-specific functions.  This makes the code much, much more complex than it needs to be.  For example, in a rewrite I did, here is what the `Shops` class looks like:

```
class Shops {
public:
    Shops(const std::string &groupfilename, const std::string &groupmovesfilename);
    Shops(std::istream &groupsfile, std::istream &movesfile);
    const std::vector<int> &getDestinationShops(int shop) const;
    std::ostream &show(int shopID, std::ostream &out = std::cout ) const;
    std::ostream &showGroups(std::ostream &out = std::cout ) const;
    const std::size_t shopCount() const { return shopgroup.size(); }
    const std::size_t groupCount() const { return groupshops.size(); }
private:
    std::unordered_map<int, int> shopgroup;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> groupshops;
};
```

The constructor receives either the file names or the two `std::istream` corresponding to two of the original files.  `show` is a convenience function similar to your `DebugPrintxx` functions, except that the knowledge of how to print out the information is captured within the object, so that it may be easily re-used if we have collections of such objects.

### Use a better algorithm

The current algorithm is very complex and difficult to follow.  It also produces incorrect results, such as listing different inventories for the same store.  Better would be to think carefully about both inputs and desired outputs and map out an algorithm for getting from one to the other.  As inspiration, here's what my rewritten `main` looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 4) {
        std::cout << "Usage: shops groupsfile movesfile stockfile\n";
        return 1;
    }
    Shops shops{argv[1], argv[2]};
    Inventory inv{argv[3]};
    inv.printAll(shops);
}
```

Much of the algorithm has now been distilled into `printAll` at the end, which may be redirected from `std::cout` to a file if desired.  Here's the algorithm I employed in code form.  First the two different style of constructor:

```
Shops::Shops(const std::string &groupfilename, const std::string &groupmovesfilename) {
    std::ifstream groupsfile{groupfilename};
    std::ifstream movesfile{groupmovesfilename};
    Shops temp{groupsfile, movesfile};
    std::swap(*this, temp);
}

Shops::Shops(std::istream &groupsfile, std::istream &movesfile) {
    skipline(groupsfile);
    int shop;
    int group;
    while (groupsfile >> shop >> group) {
        // skip zero ID shop
        if (shop != 0) {
            shopgroup[shop] = group;
            if (group != 0) {
                groupshops[group].push_back(shop);
            }
        }
    }
    // temporarily store the unaugmented groups
    auto basicgroupshops{groupshops};
    // now created the final augmented groups
    int srcGroup;
    int dstGroup;
    skipline(movesfile);
    while (movesfile >> srcGroup >> dstGroup) {
        const auto &basic{basicgroupshops[dstGroup]};
        groupshops[srcGroup].insert(groupshops[srcGroup].end(), basic.begin(), basic.end());
    }
    // for each group in augmented groups, 
    // sort and remove duplicates
    for (auto &item : groupshops)
    { 
        std::sort(item.second.begin(), item.second.end());
        item.second.erase(std::unique(item.second.begin(), item.second.end()), item.second.end());
    }
}
```

Note that `shopgroup` simply maps from a single shop number to a single shop group.  The `groupshops` maps in the opposite direction from a single shop group to a collection of shops in that group.  We then augment that using data from the shop group moves file.  That is, if we have a shop group move line that says `8  15`, we add all of the shops in group 15 to the list of destination for group 8.  Eventually, for each group have an augmented list of shops, possibly including duplicates, which are then sorted and duplicates removed.  Once that's complete, we no longer need the unaugmented groups, so that is a local variable that goes out of scope and is destroyed at the end of the constructor.

The `Inventory` class is very simple and looks like this:

```
class Inventory {
public:
    Inventory(const std::string &filename);
    std::ostream &printBasic(std::ostream &out = std::cout) const;
    std::ostream &printAll(const Shops &shops, std::ostream &out = std::cout) const;
private:
    struct ItemInventory {
        int shop;
        int qty;
    };
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<ItemInventory>> inv;
};
```

The constructor just reads in the file in the most straightforward way possible, using a `skipline` convenience function:

```
std::istream &skipline(std::istream &in) {    
    return in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
}

Inventory::Inventory(const std::string &filename) {
    std::ifstream infile{filename};
    skipline(infile);
    std::string item;
    int shop;
    int qty;
    while (infile >> item >> shop >> qty) {
        inv[item].push_back({shop, qty});
    }
};
```

The `printAll` function is then relatively simple:

```
std::ostream &Inventory::printAll(const Shops &shops, std::ostream &out) const {
    for (const auto &item: inv) {
        struct Totals {
            int total;
            int total10k;
        };
        std::unordered_map<int, Totals> itemTotals{};
        // create a map for totals for all recipient shops
        for (const auto &oneShop : item.second) {
            // count the stock from this shop
            itemTotals[oneShop.shop].total += oneShop.qty;
            itemTotals[oneShop.shop].total10k += oneShop.qty;
            // add stock to each other destination shop
            for (const auto &destShop : shops.getDestinationShops(oneShop.shop)) {
                if (oneShop.shop != destShop) {
                    itemTotals[destShop].total += oneShop.qty;
                    if (oneShop.shop < 10000) {
                        itemTotals[destShop].total10k += oneShop.qty;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (const auto &total : itemTotals) {
            out << item.first << '\t' << total.first << '\t' 
                << total.second.total << '\t' << total.second.total10k << '\n';
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

### Results

The original, with a few errors fixed, takes around 1.915 seconds on my machine with the data files from your GitLab project.  It also leaks about 80M of memory.  By contrast, the rewritten version leaks no memory and runs in 0.194 seconds, or about **10 times faster**.  Also, because the structures it keeps in memory are simpler and smaller, it has a smaller overall footprint.  Finally, it only produces a single line of output for each `stockID, shopID` pair, unlike the original, which, as I've mentioned, sometimes emits multiple lines with different totals.

### Alternative version

For complete clarity, here's the complete, working, rewritten version which omits some convenience functions mentioned above.  It's 140 lines long.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

class Shops {
public:
    Shops(const std::string &groupfilename, const std::string &groupmovesfilename);
    Shops(std::istream &groupsfile, std::istream &movesfile);
    const std::vector<int> &getDestinationShops(int shop) const;
    const std::size_t shopCount() const { return shopgroup.size(); }
    const std::size_t groupCount() const { return groupshops.size(); }
private:
    std::unordered_map<int, int> shopgroup;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> groupshops;
};

class Inventory {
public:
    Inventory(const std::string &filename);
    std::ostream &printAll(const Shops &shops, std::ostream &out = std::cout) const;
private:
    struct ItemInventory {
        int shop;
        int qty;
    };
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<ItemInventory>> inv;
};

std::istream &skipline(std::istream &in) {    
    return in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
}

Inventory::Inventory(const std::string &filename) {
    std::ifstream infile{filename};
    skipline(infile);
    std::string item;
    int shop;
    int qty;
    while (infile >> item >> shop >> qty) {
        inv[item].push_back({shop, qty});
    }
};

std::ostream &Inventory::printAll(const Shops &shops, std::ostream &out) const {
    for (const auto &item: inv) {
        struct Totals {
            int total;
            int total10k;
        };
        std::unordered_map<int, Totals> itemTotals{};
        // create a map for totals for all recipient shops
        for (const auto &oneShop : item.second) {
            // count the stock from this shop
            itemTotals[oneShop.shop].total += oneShop.qty;
            itemTotals[oneShop.shop].total10k += oneShop.qty;
            // add stock to each destination shop
            for (const auto &destShop : shops.getDestinationShops(oneShop.shop)) {
                if (oneShop.shop != destShop) {
                    itemTotals[destShop].total += oneShop.qty;
                    if (oneShop.shop < 10000) {
                        itemTotals[destShop].total10k += oneShop.qty;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (const auto &total : itemTotals) {
            out << item.first << '\t' << total.first << '\t' 
                << total.second.total << '\t' << total.second.total10k << '\n';
        }
    }
    return out;
}

Shops::Shops(const std::string &groupfilename, const std::string &groupmovesfilename) {
    std::ifstream groupsfile{groupfilename};
    std::ifstream movesfile{groupmovesfilename};
    Shops temp{groupsfile, movesfile};
    std::swap(*this, temp);
}

Shops::Shops(std::istream &groupsfile, std::istream &movesfile) {
    skipline(groupsfile);
    int shop;
    int group;
    while (groupsfile >> shop >> group) {
        // skip zero ID shop
        if (shop != 0) {
            shopgroup[shop] = group;
            if (group != 0) {
                groupshops[group].push_back(shop);
            }
        }
    }
    // temporarily store the unaugmented groups
    auto basicgroupshops{groupshops};
    // now created the final augmented groups
    int srcGroup;
    int dstGroup;
    skipline(movesfile);
    while (movesfile >> srcGroup >> dstGroup) {
        const auto &basic{basicgroupshops[dstGroup]};
        groupshops[srcGroup].insert(groupshops[srcGroup].end(), basic.begin(), basic.end());
    }
    // for each group in augmented groups, 
    // sort and remove duplicates
    for (auto &item : groupshops)
    { 
        std::sort(item.second.begin(), item.second.end());
        item.second.erase(std::unique(item.second.begin(), item.second.end()), item.second.end());
    }
}

/*
 * return a vector of destination shops for this shop
 * or throw an out_of_range error
 */
const std::vector<int> &Shops::getDestinationShops(int shop) const {
    static const std::vector<int> mt{};
    auto srcGroup{shopgroup.at(shop)};
    auto grp{groupshops.find(srcGroup)};
    if (grp == groupshops.end()) {
        return mt;
    } 
    return grp->second;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 4) {
        std::cout << "Usage: shops groupsfile movesfile stockfile\n";
        return 1;
    }
    Shops shops{argv[1], argv[2]};
    Inventory inv{argv[3]};
    inv.printAll(shops);
}
```

Comment: Edwards, thanks for a detailed answer. I'm still doing corrections to my code based on your feedback. However, I've some issues still. 1) I still have to use pointer when using unordered_map.find() method. And it's not clear how I could get rid of it. 2) Converting from WriteResult function from fprintf to << style increased total time from 1.0 seconds to 1.3 seconds. Might be, I did something wrong. 3) In ProcessShopStocks item, I'm creating AvailabilityStruct using new because of I'm adding it to unordered_map. Without using new I suspect it will be freed when out of scope. Can I avoid it?

Comment: btw, how did you measure my memory leak? Isn't memory reclaimed by OS after process quit?

Comment: My rewrite uses no pointers, so I'm quite sure it's possible.  Also, it's unlikely that `operator<<` takes more time than `fprintf`.  The cause is likely something else.  For adding things to an `unordered_map`, I used [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) in lines like this: `groupshops[group].push_back(shop);`  No pointers or `new` are required.  Note that `std::vector::push_back` creates a *copy* of the pushed element unless it can be moved as with `std::move`.

Comment: The tool I used to measure memory usage and leaks is [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) which I find to be an extremely valuable set of tools.  Although the OS will typically reclaim memory after the program exits, the problem is that by **not** freeing memory as you go, the program's memory usage will grow and grow and get slower and slower until memory is exhausted.  And then you'll be left trying to figure out how to debug a program that only crashes with certain very long input and exactly when depends on what other software is concurrently running.  Leaky software is unreliable!

Comment: I've added my complete alternative code to the answer to make it simpler to see what's been done and how.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Edward, I've checked your solution. It works for 0.2 seconds on my PC which is quit fast and I see no bugs so far. Excellent, job :) I'm still working on my version by replacing pointers with references. And there is a problem with `ProcessStockShops` function, which needs to pass a reference for previous item and I'm in doubts how to get rid of pointer there. Also, performance wise, I'm getting 1-1.2 seconds with my code, although before I saw 0.4s which might be due CPU caching. And you're reading the whole inventory file at once which improve speed greatly and it might be an issue later.

Comment: If you can guarantee that the inventory file is sorted by item number, then it would only be necessary to keep in memory just the lines with the same item number and then output as soon as the item number changes.  There seems to have been an attempt to do something like that in the original code, but the test was faulty (`sItemIDprev` is never assigned a non-NULL value) and the output was done every time.

Comment: Edward, yeah I found that sItemIDprev was not assigned. The source files is sorted because of it's dumped from database query with order by. Still not see how I could remove a pointer usage in `PostProcessItem` when summing up amounts from other groups. It looks like `->second.amount` still going to be there. BTW, I like that your solution has better algorithm due to you process only existing amounts, while I'm inserting zeroes first and later ignoring them. But it's too much difference in performance which might be due to pointers (misses CPU caching). Updated gitlab with my current version.

Answer (score 3):

### Bug

The output, `shop_stock_total.csv`, contains the following lines, each of which is a tuple of (item, shop, quantity available, quantity available excluding transfers from warehouse stores):

```
100971  1       2       2
100971  1       4       4
100971  1       6       6
```

Obviously, there should be at most one row representing item 100971 at store 1.  These results were not aggregated correctly.  There are many more occurrences of this bug.

Also note that one of your input files, `sgm.csv`, contains some duplicate entries, such as these:

```
shop_group_from shop_group_to
38  39
38  39
```

Assuming that this doesn't mean that goods magically double in quantity when moved from group 38 to 39, you'll have to be extra careful in the calculations.  Perhaps you have another bug in the part of your system that generates `sgm.csv`.

### Insanity

In my opinion, trying to accomplish this query in C++ is crazy.  Your C++ program consists of a huge amount of custom code, which is hard to understand (as evidenced by the bug above), and will likely be unmaintainable by your successor if you ever move on to another job.  Furthermore, the program does one task only, and would be a lot of work to modify it to perform any other queries.

I think that you are not using the right tool for the job.  Running queries on relational data is traditionally done using SQL, and that's what you should use.

### Suggested solution

Once you switch to an SQL-based solution, the choice of programming language becomes much less of an issue.  You could even switch to Python, like the other implementation you have in your GitLab repository.  Python even has a [built-in SQLite3 engine and library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

This solution is quite simple, readable, and maintainable.  It consists of:

- a function to import a TSV file into a database table
- a function to write the result of a SELECT query in tab-separated format
- a main function that contains the SQL query

When all of the joining and aggregation logic is expressed in one SQL query rather than spread out over several C++ functions, it's a lot easier to verify its correctness!

```python
import csv
import sqlite3

def import_table(db_conn, name, *indexes, **types):
    """
    Create a table named name based on the data in name.csv.  Columns are
    assumed to be INTEGER unless specified in types.
    """
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    with open(name + '.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
        create_stmt = 'CREATE TABLE {name} ( {col_defs} );'.format(
            name=name, 
            col_defs=', '.join(
                '{f} {type}'.format(f=f, type=types.get(f, 'INTEGER'))
                for f in reader.fieldnames
            )
        )
        cursor.execute(create_stmt)
        for i, col_group in enumerate(indexes):
            idx_stmt = 'CREATE INDEX {name}{i} ON {name} ({col_list});'.format(
                name=name,
                i=i,
                col_list=', '.join(col_group)
            )
            cursor.execute(idx_stmt)
        insert_stmt = 'INSERT INTO {name} VALUES ({placeholders});'.format(
            name=name,
            placeholders=', '.join('?' for _ in reader.fieldnames)
        )
        cursor.executemany(insert_stmt, (list(row.values()) for row in reader))

def query(out, db_conn, select_stmt, *params):
    """
    Execute a SELECT statement and write the results in tab-separated format
    to a file-like object.
    """
    cursor = db_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(select_stmt, *params)
    fieldnames = [d[0] for d in cursor.description]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(dict(zip(fieldnames, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall())

def main():
    db_conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    import_table(db_conn, 'sgm', ['shop_group_to'])
    import_table(db_conn, 'shopgroups', ['shopgroup_id'])
    import_table(db_conn, 'shopstock_all', ['shop_id', 'item_idx'],
        item_idx='TEXT'
    )
    db_conn.commit()
    with open('shop_stock_total.csv', 'w') as out:
        query(out, db_conn, '''
            WITH shop_sources AS (
                SELECT shop_id                      -- Each shop has access to
                     , shop_id AS source_shop_id    -- its own stuff,
                     , 1 AS not_from_warehouse      -- even if it's a warehouse
                    FROM shopgroups
                UNION
                SELECT shop.shop_id                 -- A shop may also access
                     , source.shop_id               -- stuff from its group,
                     , source.shop_id < 10000       -- noting if from warehouse
                    FROM shopgroups AS shop
                        INNER JOIN sgm
                            ON shop.shopgroup_id = sgm.shop_group_to
                        INNER JOIN shopgroups AS source
                            ON sgm.shop_group_from = source.shopgroup_id
                    WHERE shop.shopgroup_id <> 0
                        AND shop.shop_id <> source.shop_id
            )
            SELECT inv.item_idx AS item_idx
                 , ss.shop_id AS shop_id
                 , SUM(inv.amount) AS amount
                 , SUM(inv.amount * not_from_warehouse) AS amount_excl_warehouses
                FROM shop_sources AS ss
                    INNER JOIN shopstock_all AS inv
                        ON ss.source_shop_id = inv.shop_id
                GROUP BY inv.item_idx, ss.shop_id
                ORDER BY inv.item_idx, ss.shop_id;
        ''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### What about performance?

Is the solution above faster than your C++ program?  Admittedly, no: it takes about twice as long.  However, consider what steps you can easily take to improve its performance:

- Switch to a more capable database system than SQLite (such as PostgreSQL)
- Keep the inventory data in the SQL database, already in memory, so that you don't have to spend time loading CSV files
- Use materialized views and triggers to automatically regenerate the query results whenever inventory levels change
- Take the money that you saved by not spending so much time on maintaining the code, and use it to buy faster hardware

Comment: 200_success, thanks for pointing to the bug. I'll need to verify it. The .csv files are retrieved from database (sgm is filled manually to the database, that's why it could contains duplicates.) Of course, items are not moved twice from shop to shop in that case. We had initial implementation using SQL query and it was very slow (minutes to run) on our mysql server. The server itself is powerful enough. That's why we've rewritten the solution using csv offload, python processing and than .csv loading. This way it's much faster than doing this in SQL. I could post SQL and tables, so you'll see.

Comment: Minutes? This SQLite query ran in a few seconds on an old laptop. Perhaps you should have your SQL schema and query reviewed instead of this gigantic workaround.

Comment: In any case, I agree that the SQL-based version would be an excellent candidate for another question here.

Comment: 200_success, yep, you was right. There are bugs. I did 'cat shop_stock_total.csv | sort |less' and there are lots of duplicates. All with the same values as I see but this is wrong any way. I'll need to find out how it's happening.

Comment: posted an [sql version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/198363/calculating-effective-shop-inventories-sql)

Comment: 200_success, I've checked you python version. It produces incorrect results (file does not match to results produced by C++ version. However, your code looks really pythonic. I like it. I would use it as a style-guide to fix my old python scripts.

Comment: It's quite possible that I have misinterpreted the requirements. However, I wouldn't trust your C++ results to be authoritative either. I suggest making some minimal unit tests to figure out which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the issues are answered by Edward in the first answer.
However, the suggested by Edward solution is slower than my current. So I've decided to post mine.

**Rationale for changes**

1. There're no `ShopGroup` structures anymore. Since `group` is not
   used any further except inside `shops`. I've decided to use `group`
   only internally inside `Shops` class.
2. During processing of shops. The shop item itself is included as target shop for itself. This helps to avoid processing shop for itself separately. Instead, it happens during for-cycle like all others destinations.
3. Using `at()` method of `unordered_map` helps to pass argument with `const` declaration and it does not require to create static empty vector.
4. `Shops` with `group_id` equal to `0` have special meaning - "no group specified". Thus, in spite of all such `shops` have the same `group_id` - there are no movements between them. I had to add a special magic_number there to avoid moving between those shops. This is bad - but I don't see how to fix this without lots of complications.
5. Both classes could be static. Since there's only single object exists during lifetime of application. I've decided not to use static. Guess, it could be better in case of reusing those objects later. And due to this, I still have a separate header file.

   P.S. I've decided not to use parameters for filenames since this is not required
   P.P.S when line is wrapped - my editor add 2 tabs instead of 1 (guess, this is easier to read. I didn't find any issues with the formatting of original code). And yes, manual code folding

   `// {{{ comment`

   // code goes here

   `// }}}`

   are looking nice. And it allows better grouping of code blocks than all IDEs code folding I've seen, IMHO.

**shop-stock-total.h**

---

```
// {{{ Structures, typedefs and classes
// {{{ Shops
class Shops {
public:
    Shops(const std::string& shop_groups_filename, 
            const std::string& groups_moves_filename);
    const std::vector<int>& getToShops(int shop_id) const;
private:
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> shops_to_shops;
};
// }}}
// {{{
struct ItemStockStruct {
    int totalAmount;
    int totalAmount10k;
};
// }}}
// {{{ ShopsStocksProcessor
class ShopsStocksProcessor {
public:
    ShopsStocksProcessor(const Shops& shops, const std::string& stock_filename,
            const std::string& out_filename);
private:
    void save_item_stock(std::ofstream& out, const std::string& item_id,
        const std::unordered_map<int, ItemStockStruct>& item_stock);
};
// }}}
// }}}
// {{{ Functions
// {{{ generic
// {{{ skipline
std::istream &skipline(std::istream &in);     
// }}}
// }}}
// }}}
```

---

**shop-stock-total.cpp**

---

```
// {{{ standard and other includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <set>
// }}}
// {{{ filenames 
const char *SHOP_GROUP_MOVES_FILE = "sgm.csv";
const char *SHOP_GROUPS_FILE = "shopgroups.csv";
const char *SHOP_STOCKS_FILE = "shopstock_all.csv";
const char *SHOP_STOCK_TOTALS_FILE = "shop_stock_total.csv";
// }}}

#include "shop-stock-total.h"

// {{{ Shops
// {{{ Shops::Shops
Shops::Shops(const std::string& shop_groups_filename, 
            const std::string& groups_moves_filename) {

    int shop_id, group_id;

    // temporary storage for shops and groups
    std::unordered_map<int, int> shops;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> groups;


    // read file and store shops and groups
    std::ifstream shop_groups_file{shop_groups_filename};
    skipline(shop_groups_file);
    int magic_group_id = 100000;
    while (shop_groups_file >> shop_id >> group_id) {
        if (shop_id == 0) continue;
        if (group_id == 0) group_id = magic_group_id++;
        shops[shop_id] = group_id; 
        groups[group_id].push_back(shop_id);
    }

    // add shops from the same group
    for (const auto& shop: shops) {
        shops_to_shops[shop.first].insert(shops_to_shops[shop.first].end(),
                groups[shops[shop.first]].begin(),
                groups[shops[shop.first]].end());
    }

    // read group moves file and add toShops from the toGroup into
    // all corresponding fromGroup shops
    int groupFrom, groupTo;
    std::ifstream group_moves_file{groups_moves_filename};
    skipline(group_moves_file);
    while (group_moves_file >> groupFrom >> groupTo) {

        for (auto shop_id : groups[groupFrom]) {
            shops_to_shops[shop_id].insert(shops_to_shops[shop_id].end(),
                    groups[groupTo].begin(),
                    groups[groupTo].end());
        }
    }

    // erase shop itself from it's own list,
    // sort and remove dupes
    for (auto& shop: shops_to_shops) {
        // de duping via set and back to vector
        std::set<int> s(
            shop.second.begin(),
            shop.second.end()
        );

        //assign back to vector
        shop.second.assign(s.begin(), s.end());
    }

}
// }}}
// {{{ Shops::getToShops
const std::vector<int>& Shops::getToShops(int shop_id) const {
    return shops_to_shops.at(shop_id);
}
// }}}
// }}}
// {{{ ShopsStocksProcessor
// {{{ ProcessShopStocks
ShopsStocksProcessor::ShopsStocksProcessor(const Shops& shops,
        const std::string& stock_filename,
        const std::string& out_filename) {

    std::string item_id, item_prev_id = "";
    int shop_id, amount;
    std::ifstream stock_file{stock_filename};
    std::ofstream out{out_filename};

    std::unordered_map<int, ItemStockStruct> item_stock;

    // reading file
    skipline(stock_file);
    while (stock_file >> item_id >> shop_id >> amount) {

        // if item has changed than output the previous one
        if (item_id.compare(item_prev_id) != 0) {
            save_item_stock(out, item_prev_id, item_stock);
            item_stock.clear();
            item_prev_id = item_id;
        }

        for (const auto s: shops.getToShops(shop_id)) {
            item_stock[s].totalAmount += amount;
            if (shop_id < 10000) item_stock[s].totalAmount10k += amount;
        }
    }
    if (item_id.length() > 0) {
        save_item_stock(out, item_id, item_stock);
    }
}
// }}}
// {{{ save_item_stock
void ShopsStocksProcessor::save_item_stock(std::ofstream& out, const std::string& item_id,
        const std::unordered_map<int, ItemStockStruct>& item_stock) {
    for (const auto& item : item_stock) {
        out << item_id << "\t" << item.first << "\t"
            << item.second.totalAmount << "\t"
            << item.second.totalAmount10k << "\n";
    }
}
// }}}
// }}}
// {{{ skipline (thx Edward from CodeReview @ StackExchange
std::istream &skipline(std::istream &in) {    
    return in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
}
// }}}
// {{{ main
int main() {

    ShopsStocksProcessor(
            Shops(SHOP_GROUPS_FILE, SHOP_GROUP_MOVES_FILE),
            SHOP_STOCKS_FILE, SHOP_STOCK_TOTALS_FILE); 

    return 0;
}
// }}}
```

---

An original Makefile is used.

**Performance**

Well, this version is slightly (**5-10%**) faster than Edward's solution. And it keeps only inventory of single item in memory based on assumption that `shopstock_all.csv` is sorted by `item_idx` field. Code is updated on [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/pk72/shop-stock-total).